# ATtiny861 pin change interrupt on PA.2: error in datasheet?

Tags: avr, interrupts, datasheet, attiny, gpio-external-interrupt

I faced with some confusion in subject datasheet:

In one section PA.2 should be masking by PCIE1 bit as PA.2 is PCINT2 input and it should be within PCINT[7:0] and PCINT[15:12] range:

[image]

On the other hand PA.2 (PCINT2) will generate Pin change interrupt 0:

[image]

Is there something that I misunderstood? Or I just faced with a rare case of an error in documentation?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, errors in documentation aren't that rare, especially with companies that make tons of large documents.

In this case, my experience is that the register description and Pin-Package drawing are correct. As you should expect. Register interactions are documented during chip design, as is pin-out, whereas those tables are an after-though during or after testing.

I have not had problems with these exact chips going by register descriptions for the PCINTs (never use those tables) and I'm sure I have used PA2 for interrupts several times now, though I have used so many Atmels, it's all a bit of a blur.

### EDIT:

Though seeing as the number of pins that are of different PCIE group is also not consistent on further look (2 mentioned in the table, 4 implied in the register description) I do advise a test. You-never-knows strong in this one are.